# CorelDraw VBA "file open" macro not working

Tags: vba, coreldraw

I am using the following code for a file open dialogue to open a CDR file in CorelDraw.  It will pull up the dialogue, however, I have to use Alt+Tab to see it.  Also, many times, it causes the application to freeze completely.  Any ideas?

```
Private Sub cmdCDRFile_Click()
Dim str As String
  Dim objFileDialog As Office.FileDialog
  Dim objFileDialogFilters As Office.FileDialogFilters
  Dim CDRFileOject As Excel.Application
  Set CDRFileOject = New Excel.Application

  Set objFileDialog = CDRFileOject.Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogType.msoFileDialogFilePicker)
  If CDRInitialFolder = "" Then
      CDRInitialFolder = "C:\Users\<user name here>\Desktop"
  End If
  With objFileDialog

      'define a Filters object
      Set objFileDialogFilters = .Filters
      With objFileDialogFilters

'clear the default filters
         .Clear

'add a filter, all filters must start with an asterisk
         .Add "CDR template Files", "*.CDR"
      End With
      .InitialFileName = CDRInitialFolder

      'allow only one file to be selected
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
      Dim hxl As Long
      hxl = FindWindowA("XLMAIN", "Excel")
      If (hxl <> 0) Then
        res = SetForegroundWindow(hxl)
      End If
      'show the dialog and exit if Cancel is pressed
      If objFileDialog.Show = 0 Then
         Exit Sub
      End If
  End With

  txtCDRFile.Text = objFileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
  CDRFileOject.Quit
  Set CDRFileOject = Nothing
  CDRInitialFolder = Left(txtCDRFile.Text, InStrRev(txtCDRFile.Text, "\"))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Palmetto Wood Shop!

First of all, I guess you are in some UserForm, in Office (Access or Excel).
I believe you need to use FileDialog without setting an Excel Application.

I know you set filters to .CDR and Initial folders, but try this code (a simplified one) to see if your performance improve.

If you click to receive only the string of name of file and folder I believe it should be a Function.

In CallFunction SUB you can call and put the results in their places like "txtCDRFile.Text" textbox

```
Private Function Selecting_Files()
 Dim f As Object

 Set f = Application.FileDialog(3)
     f.AllowMultiSelect = False
     f.Show

     SelectedFiles = f.SelectedItems.Count

     If SelectedFiles < 1 Then
       MsgBox "None file Selected", vbOKOnly, "Error"
       Exit Function
     End If

     File_Fullname = f.SelectedItems(1)
     File_Folder = Left(File_Fullname, InStrRev(File_Fullname, "\"))
     File_Name = Mid(File_Fullname, InStrRev(File_Fullname, "\") + 1, Len(File_Fullname) - InStrRev(File_Fullname, "\"))

     Selecting_Files = File_Fullname & "§" & File_Folder & "§" & File_Name

End Function

Sub CallFunction()

   FileDetails = Selecting_Files()

   SplitFileDetails = Split(FileDetails, "§")

   File_Fullname = SplitFileDetails(0)
   File_Folder = SplitFileDetails(1)
   File_Name = SplitFileDetails(2)

   MsgBox File_Fullname
   MsgBox File_Folder
   MsgBox File_Name

End Sub
```